# linq to entities Not in statement

Tags: linq, entity-framework

I am new to linq to entities. I am trying to do a not in statement and when i run it i am getting noting back. But if i run the SQL equivalent i get data back.

The SQL statement that i am trying to replicate is

```
SELECT * FROM [SCRAPREASON] WHERE [CODE] NOT IN (SELECT [CODE] FROM [QUALITYALERTRULE]) ORDER BY [CODE]
```

The Linq i have at the moment is

```
  var DefectCode = PumaOEEEntities.ScrapReasons
     .Where(x => !PumaOEEEntities.QualityAlertRules.Any(y => y.Code != x.Code))
     .Select(x => new { GroupID = x.Code}).ToList();
```

Can anyone see what i am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should compare codes for equality (`==` instead of `!=`):

```
 var reasons = PumaOEEEntities.ScrapReasons
     .Where(x => !PumaOEEEntities.QualityAlertRules.Any(y => y.Code == x.Code))
     .OrderBy(x => x.Code)
     .ToList();
```

Generated SQL will look like:

```
SELECT
    [Extent1].[Code] AS [Code],
    // Other columns
    FROM [dbo].[ScrapReasons] AS [Extent1]
    WHERE  NOT EXISTS (SELECT
        1 AS [C1]
        FROM [dbo].[QualityAlertRules] AS [Extent2]
        WHERE [Extent2].[Code] = [Extent1].[Code]
    )
    ORDER BY [Extent1].[Code] ASC
```

Comment: Add the order by and it looks perfect.

Answer (score 0):

You can try `Except` like this

```
var DefectCode = PumaOEEEntities.ScrapReasons.Select(x=>x.Code)
                .Except(PumaOEEEntities.QualityAlertRules.Select(y=>y.Code)).ToList();
```

Comment: That will return only `Code` column

Comment: I think OP also trying to get the list of `code`. Am I missing someting?

Comment: You are missing that OP is trying to replicate sql query which has `SELECT * FROM`